# Who did the apostles know as their and their forefathers’ God in Acts 3:13?

Tags: acts

Acts 3:13 ASV

The God of Abraham, and of Isaac, and of Jacob, the God of our fathers, hath glorified his Servant Jesus; whom ye delivered up, and denied before the face of Pilate, when he had determined to release him.

Comment: What question are you asking.  It is not clear at all - has it not been answered in the question?  Is this a thinly disguised provocative question?

Comment: @Dottard. Just as your previous Q, God God to some is, The Father, generally, sometimes, though not always Jesus sometimes, the holy spirit

Comment: If that is your question then it should be closed.  For the unitarian (and JW) it is the Father only; for the binitarian, God is the Father and Jesus; for the trinitarian, God is the Father Son and Holy Spirit.  None of this can be deduced from the text you quote.

Comment: @Dottard. Your previous Q about Lord, which has OT back ground, which I answered. Is similar to this question. Why do you now say it should be closed. If you say it is already answered in the q then it is clear to you. So why do you say it is not clear at all?

Comment: ... because it requires a theological and not a textual/hermeneutics answer.  This question is another in a parade of such questions from you about exactly the same topic - Arianism vs trinitarianism.  Are you aware that there are other topics in Biblical hermeneutics?  That is, it is a "Who/what is God?" question which is off-topic.

Comment: @Dottard. I can use the same reason for your previous Q. Why not let reason prevail. This is clearly not a what is God question. It is a who Q.